# Sencha Touch can not open camera

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have created a hybrid app using Sencha Touch 2.4, Sencha Cmd 5.0 and Cordova 3.5

The view for the app looks like

```
Ext.define('CameraApp.view.Main', {
   extend: 'Ext.Container',

   requires: [
      'Ext.Button',
      'Ext.Img'
   ],

   config: {
      items: [
         {
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: function(button, e) {
               Ext.device.Camera.capture({
                  source: 'camera',
                  destination: 'file',
                  success: function(url) {
                     var img = Ext.getCmp("Image");
                     img.setSrc(url);
                  }
               });
            },
            text: 'Take photo'
         },
         {
            xtype: 'image',
            height: 201,
            id: 'Image',
            src: 'white.png'
         }
      ]
   }
});
```

And the `app.js` looks like

```
Ext.application({
   requires: [
      'Ext.device.Camera'
   ],
   views: [
      'Main'
   ],
   name: 'CameraApp',
   launch: function() {
      Ext.create('CameraApp.view.Main', {fullscreen: true});
   }
});
```

When I click the button it comes with the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined`

Do anybody know how to fix it?

I have already added the plugin for the camera to the cordova-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of I forgot to add `remote: true` in

```
{
   "path": "cordova.js"
}
```

In `app.json`